# GWT - sleep\wait for signal?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am looking for a good way to perform sleep() or waitForEvent() in GWT\Javascript.
I am performing a http request and i don't want to continue execution of the code before the request ends.

I am using an existing code so it is very problematic to re-factor it to wait for an event.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: errr, callbacks? think of it this way, if the request takes "forever", will the user wait for "forever" before doing something else?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a flow control library like [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js).

```
    Frame(function(next){
        $.ajax({
            url:'authenticate.api',
            data: id,
            success: next
        });
    });
    Frame(function(next, ajaxResponse){
        userRole = ajaxResponse.responseText.userRole;
    });
```